# Can not execute a DDL with Statement DB(postgres) - Java

Tags: java, postgresql, ddl

I need to make a DDL Statement by updating the database (new tables, fields and keys).

But only when I try to add tables with foreign keys and modify tables by adding foreign keys does not work, get error, but the application is paused indefinitely.

For example:

```
instanceStatement.execute ("ALTER TABLE pay ADD CONSTRAINT foranea_pay_customer FOREIGN KEY (customerid) REFERENCES customer (customerid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;");
```

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE
  ADD CONSTRAINT pay foranea_pay_customer -- <<-- one token too many here
   FOREIGN KEY (customerid)
    REFERENCES customer (customerid)
     ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
  ;
```

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE pay -- <<-- maybe here ???
  ADD CONSTRAINT foranea_pay_customer
   FOREIGN KEY (customerid)
    REFERENCES customer (customerid)
     ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
  ;
```